# Android - Manage 3rd Apps Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

In the Android Application I am developing, I have to manage third-party application's notifications. As far as I know, there is no way to make a specific app manage other apps notification (turn them ON or OFF) only if the device is rooted.

Is there anyone who has been dealing with the same issue and found out a suitable solution?

Comment: `As far as I know, there is no way to make a specific app manage other apps notification` You already have the **perfect answer**.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure about that, but i just wanted to see if i left something that someone else may knew it.

Comment: It would be a great security issue, if other apps could take control of your notifications. Don't you agree?

Comment: Absolutely, but sometimes we need this feature. unfortunately it's not possible ever.